# About javascript, Array.sort() function

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var arr = [];
console.log(arr)
arr.push( something )
console.log(arr) 
arr.push( something )
console.log(arr)
arr.push( something ) 
console.log(arr)
arr.sort(somefunction())
console.log(arr)
```

In Chrome and FireFox, the output is like

```
[]
[object]
[object,object]
[object,object,object]
[object,object,object]
```

but when I expand the array for details, all of the result is the array after sort.

```
[object,object,object] 
[object,object,object] 
[object,object,object] 
[object,object,object] 
[object,object,object]
```

Is this the bug of the Browser, JavaScript or just an error I made in my code.

Comment: It's a mistake you made in thinking what "expand for details" means. This is neither a bug nor an error in the code

Comment: Btw, `.sort(someFunction())` is possibly a mistake and should be `.sort(someFunction)`, but that's not relevant to this question

Comment: Thanks, I'll check out what "expand for details"means.